# Selenium , cant find a submit button on login (AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'findElement'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

```
driver.get( 'https://app.quantdata.us/login')

cookies = driver.get_cookies()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

driver.find_element("id","username").send_keys(username)#works
driver.find_element("id","password").send_keys(password)#works


driver.find_element("id","submit").click() #not working 
driver.findElement("class","submit").click();#notworking
driver.find_element("xpath","//*[@id=__next]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/button").click()#not working
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[type=submit]').submit() #not working 
 
driver.find_element("id","submit").click() #not working 
driver.findElement("class","submit").click();#notworking
driver.find_element("xpath","//*[@id=__next]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/button").click()#not working
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[type=submit]').submit() #not working
```

Comment: Use [Explicit Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait) as well as correct syntax: `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@type="submit"]'))).click()`

Answer (score 0):

The error

> (AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'findElement'

is cuased because your code is in Python. So with Python you should use `find_element` method while in one line you are using Java stile `driver.findElement("class","submit").click();`
So, you just need to use Python style there too:

```py
driver.find_element(By.CLASS, 'submit')
```

Also, you probably need to use `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit waits as mentioned by Barry to wait for element clickability